# Can you view transactions that are queued up for the next ledger?

Tags: transactions, dex

Is there a way for anyone to view the transactions that are pending for the next ledger BEFORE they get processed/posted to the next ledger? this can be very valuable if you are trading on the Stellar DEX and want to see the orders that are about to hit, e.g., you want to view the "pending" order book before it becomes the next order book.

Comment: Please check my answer here: https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/679/366

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is unlikely. At least there are no APIs to do so directly.

The functionality that you mentioned could cause `front-running`, which is surely not a good idea for any financial-oriented system.

Moreover, there is no guarantee when a tx would be included in a ledger. Most commonly the txs are included in the next ledger, but sometimes not.